# Gaussian Blur Filter Reversal: iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, gaussian

I've got a gaussian blur which I'm doing for an app.

```
    //Get a UIImage from the UIView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Blur the UIImage
    CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImage.CGImage];
    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:resultImage];

    //Place the UIImage in a UIImageView
    newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    newView.image = endImage;
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
```

It works great, but I want to be able to reverse it and return the view back to normal.

How can I do this as trying to simply remove the blur's view from it's superview didn't work. I've also tried setting various properties to nil with no luck.

Comment: Can't you just make a copy of viewImage before the blur is applied and revert when you want to reverse?

Comment: How do I make a copy of it without subsequently changing both copies once the blur is applied?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140306/4124168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a pointer to viewImage in a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* originalImage;
```

then after

```
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

add

```
self.originalImage = viewImage;
```

To revert your image:

```
newView.image = self.originalImage;
```

when you apply the blur it does not alter viewImage.. you have created a separate CIImage which gets blurred, and you make a new UIImage from the blurred CIImage.

Comment: This made me realize that what I'm doing overall is incorrect. I'm trying make my self.view blur because I'm putting some objects temporarily over the top of it. I do not want an original image, but instead to go back to the view that I was originally on. You're answer is correct, but do you think you could edit your answer to reflect that? I wish I could give you two checkmarks for this :P

Comment: I ended up just creating a UIView with a blur on it, then getting rid of it that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- First thing i saw in your code is that you don't apply the filter in a async task. blur the image take time, so if you don't want to freeze the main thread you should use:

---

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //blur the image in a second thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //set the blurred image to your imageView in the main thread
    });
});
```

---

- To can reverse the original image, you just put the blurred copy in other imageView that appear over the original. In my case the original image isn't a imageView, but the view itself. So i only add a imageView in my view to set the blurred image, and set to nil when i want to reverse.

---

- Finally, if you want to avoid the blink when you set the blurred image, you can play with alpha in animations to make a soft transition:

---

```
[self.blurredImageView setAlpha: 0.0]; //make the imageView invisible
[self.blurredImageView setImage:blurredImage];
//and after set the image, make it visible slowly.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             [self.blurredImageView setAlpha: 1.0]; 
                         }
                         completion:nil];
```

---

- Here is my complete methods:

---

```
- (void)makeBlurredScreenShot{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CIContext *context   = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageView.CGImage];

    // Apply clamp filter:
    // this is needed because the CIGaussianBlur when applied makes
    // a trasparent border around the image
    NSString *clampFilterName = @"CIAffineClamp";
    CIFilter *clamp = [CIFilter filterWithName:clampFilterName];
    if (!clamp)
        return;

    [clamp setValue:sourceImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    CIImage *clampResult = [clamp valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

    // Apply Gaussian Blur filter
    NSString *gaussianBlurFilterName = @"CIGaussianBlur";
    CIFilter *gaussianBlur           = [CIFilter filterWithName:gaussianBlurFilterName];
    if (!gaussianBlur)
        return;

    [gaussianBlur setValue:clampResult forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [gaussianBlur setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8.0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    CIImage *gaussianBlurResult = [gaussianBlur valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:gaussianBlurResult fromRect:[sourceImage extent]];

        UIImage *blurredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.blurredImageView setAlpha: 0.0];
            [self.blurredImageView setImage:blurredImage];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                             animations:^{
                                 [self.blurredImageView setAlpha: 1.0]; 
                             }
                             completion:nil];
        });
    });
}
```

---

```
- (void)removeBlurredScreenShot{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                          [self.blurredImageView setAlpha: 0.0];
                             }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                          [self.blurredImageView setImage:nil];
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my previous comment, you could create a property/iVar that holds the image before the effect is applied and revert in case you want to undo.

```
if(!_originalImage)
    _originalImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

_originalImage = viewImage; //(Creates a copy, not a C-Type pass-by-reference)

// Do your Blur Stuff

// Now somewhere down the line in your program, if you don't like the blur and the user would like to undo:

viewImage = _originalImage;
```

As per your comment on @HeWas's answer, you shouldn't blur the view completely. If the view is getting blurred, there's something else you are doing wrong elsewhere in your program.